# Using own bt_navigator in Humble

Tags: navigation, ros2, plugin, nav2

Hello ROS 2 Navigators,

I am working in ROS 2 Humble Nav2 stack, There's a tutorial in Nav2 for Writing a New Navigator plugin but I can't find navigators parameter in the Nav2 Humble Version, I want to get to know that, Is it possible to use own bt navigator instead NavigateToPose in Humble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, only Iron and newer has the plugin-based navigators -- please upgrade!

Comment: Since Humble is LTS, is there any plan for this feature in upcoming releases in humble?

Comment: No, see above...